# Adding words to an arraylist with concurrently running threads

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrency

i have created a static field with type ArrayList

```
public static ArrayList<String> infiList;
```

I need to add three concurrently running threads under the main method, the three threads should repeatedly add words to infiList with the following rules:

1) In each loop pass, the thread should add exactly one word to infiList.

2) If the last word in infiList is currently “This”, the thread should append word “is” to infiList.

3) If the last word in infiList is currently “is”, the thread should append word “infinite” to infiList.

4) If the last word in infiList is currently “infinite”, or if infiList is still empty, the thread should append word “This” to infiList.

5) At any time, infiList should contain “This” only at the beginning of the list or directly after an occurrence of “infinite”, “is” should occur in the list only directly after a “This”, and an “infinite” should occur only directly after an “is”. No other words are allowed in infiList.

For Example: after a while, infiList should contain the following list of strings: “This”, “is”, “infinite”, “This”, “is”,
“infinite”, “This”, “is”, “infinite”, “This”, “is”, “infinite”, “This”, “is”, ...

How do I get started with doing this, how do I make a concurrently running thread that adds words to an arraylist??

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want the full implementation of threads and stuff in Java you should read up, we are not here to solve that. If you have an issue with the threads accessing the ArrayList then my answer covers it

Comment: Do some reading and start, we can't help if you don't do the effort

Answer (score 1):

You should crate a synchronization object. and before accessing the ArrayList each thread should make a call to `synchronized(syncObject){//code will go here}` before accessing the arrayList you do not have data race events happening.

And each thread will simply check what's the last word in the arraylist and then append the proper one after that

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about ordering threads

Comment: It's about ordering the threads? there is no order in the threads, each thread checks what's the last word in the list and then appends the proper next one depending on that

Comment: @EngineerDollery in the question it does not say that each thread is responsible for one word only. Downvote uncalled for

Comment: @EngineerDollery maybe you are correct and that is what he wanted, but it is not stated in the question

Answer (score 1):

As the [Javadoc for ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) says:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.  (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.)

You can synchronize on the `ArrayList` itself:

```
synchronized (infiList) {
  // ... Whatever logic to make structural modifications to the list.
  // e.g. infiList.add(something);
}
```

Note that you should not use `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` to wrap `infiList`, since you describe logic like "if a value is in the list, then add something". You need to have exclusive access to the list for both the get and the add here, since otherwise the condition could cease to be true after the get.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about thread ordering

Comment: I don't see that in the question. If it is the case, your suggested duplicate is wrong too.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, the question doesn't say anything about thread ordering.  And anyway, the order in which the threads run in the assigment does not matter because they are just workers:  All three threads perform exactly the same task.

Comment: The OP wants the words This Is Infinite in order -- the question doesn't seem to be about simple concurrent access to threads

Comment: @JohnDemetriou likewise.

Comment: You shouldn't upvote because a downvote was uncalled for -- that's not what they're for. All you have to do, as you have, is explain my misunderstanding and I'll take the downvote away, which I have. Simple.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, read the assignment again.  The fact that the number of threads equals the number of words is pure coincidence.  Each thread is supposed to examine the last word in the list, and then append the appropriate next word.  As long as the OP can prevent the threads from interfering with one another, it'll all be good.